# read a python dictionary (non standard file?)

Tags: python, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

I am given an ASCI file with this format:

```
my_dictionary = {
    (1,0): "myvalue1",
    (1,1): "myvalue2"
}
```

if the file was like this:

```
{
    (1,0): "myvalue1",
    (1,1): "myvalue2"
}
```

then this code would work:

```
file = open(myfile, "r")
contents = file.read()
mydic = ast.literal_eval(contents)
```

but in my situation there is a crash due to the first line of the ASCII file, is there a way to read also the variable name?

Comment: `varname, contents = file.read().split("=")` Then use `contents` as you already did and store variable name somewhere (e.g. as a key of dict-of-dicts, if you have more files with that format). :)

Comment: @h4z3, that should really use `.split("=", 1)` so that the presence of an additional equals sign (in a dictionary string value, most likely) won't cause an error.

Comment: both make ast crash with a SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: they work, my file contained \n which was the problem of the crash

Answer (score 1):

A basic split on `" = "` will work in cases when you only have one "assignment" in your file, but if you have multiple instances of variable assignment with dictionaries, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools as it, ast, re
f = """
 my_dictionary = {
    (1,0): "myvalue1",
    (1,1): "myvalue2"
 }
 my_dictionary1 = {
    (1,0): "myvalue2",
    (1,1): "myvalue3"
 }
"""
r = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in it.groupby(filter(None, f.split('\n')), key=lambda x:'=' in x)]
d = {re.findall('\w+(?=\s\=)', r[i][-1][0])[0]:ast.literal_eval( \
        re.findall('\{(?:[\w\W]+)*', r[i][-1][0])[0]+'\n'.join(r[i+1][-1]))
           for i in range(0, len(r)-1, 2)}
```

Output:

```
{'my_dictionary': {(1, 0): 'myvalue1', (1, 1): 'myvalue2'}, 'my_dictionary1': {(1, 0): 'myvalue2', (1, 1): 'myvalue3'}}
```